# Deep link in android app

Tags: android

I implemented deep link in my android app. Whenever I clicked the share link its open my app perfectly. 
My problem is copy the share link and paste the chrome browser it doesn't open my app.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: is it searching in google?

Comment: try adding the manifest - link (obfuscating private datas) so we can check it :)

Comment: The chrome browser doesn't send the ```view``` intent. This is a known behaviour.

Comment: i added scheme and host name in my manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is an application.

By trying to use deep link in Chrome, you are actually trying to **open an app(your app) from another app(Chrome)** which is not really what deep link does!

To test your deep link, enter link in default browser of your phone(mostly it is Google Search). And as you say, it is opening. So your deep link is working **perfectly fine** and you don't need to worry about that.

Now, **How to make share link work from Chrome:**

For that,  you need to use 'a href' tag that will be defined on your website! Moreover, you need to implement **App Link** instead of simple deep link. You can refer to this answer here for this [Deep Link not working in Chrome for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192778/deep-link-not-working-in-chrome-for-android) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually click on a link pointing to that URL to trigger the deep-link Intent, writing the URL manually doesn't trigger it.